# Does SE have any policies I should be aware of before requesting a text transcript of an audio recording

Tags: discussion, support, transcription

I have a recording where someone was talking about a piano's having some kind of problem, but I couldn't find out what it was due to primarily being hard-of-hearing. I can't find anybody to help me transcribe it.

A few years ago, I asked to have some things identified based on a video I took, but since I didn't upload it on YouTube, they said that it seemed to be a waste of bandwidth for someone to download the file rather than have it streamed.

If I have an MP3 file I'd like to use as part of a question, what is the recommended option to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, transcription in general is off topic on this site so the question is off topic.

Honestly, if it's just trying to get text from someone speaking you may be able to have software do most of it.  In fact i suggest go taking a peek at the software recs SE to see if someone has already requested software that transcribes audio clips and if not it may make sense to ask for it. YouTube has both auto generated captions and user submitted captions also.